# python keras.preprocessing.sequence has no attribute pad_sequences

Tags: python

import:`from keras.preprocessing import sequence`

but:
AttributeError: module 'keras.preprocessing.sequence' has no attribute 'pad_sequences'

Why?

How can I edit this?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like your keras version is greater than 2.8 that's why getting error as

`from keras.preprocessing import sequence`

works for earlier version. Instead, replace with the below given code:

`from keras.utils.data_utils import pad_sequences`

You can also use:

`from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences`

They both worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `keras_preprocessing` instead `keras.preprocessing`:

```py
from keras_preprocessing import sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can use the `tf.keras` version of `pad_sequences` directly from TensorFlow.

Just use:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
```